# Scale calculation PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I need to calculate the scale for the selected polygons so that they fit into the given paper sizes. This should be calculated automatically, without user interaction. How can I do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Polygons don't have a scale, the map does. Also, who gives the paper sizes? What are they used for? Why do the polygons need to fit them? What have you tried?

Comment: You can use python to get all of the vertices of the polygon.  Then get the max X min X max Y min Y and then scale these to fit an 8-1/2 x 11" piece of paper depending if you want X to be the long edge or short edge.